# Difference between ことから and から

Tags: grammar, nuances

Are there any differences in intonation if used in a sentence like this?

> 支持率が高い**ことから/から**、多くの国民が新内閣に期待していることがわかる

Comment: It is hard to say if there is any real difference in meaning in this particular sentence. But から as a conjunction (that connects sentences) is **very subjective**. から as a case marker is neutral. You may think ことから is short for ことから考えて・判断して, ことを理由に, etc.

Comment: (終止形+)から is 接続助詞(conjunctive particle) meaning "because", while (こと+)から is 格助詞(case particle) meaning "from". ～～ことから・・・がわかる means "You can see ・・・ judging from the fact that ～～"

Comment: Oh, are you asking about just the difference in intonation / pitch accent? They are [たかいことから]{LHLLLLL} or [たかいことから]{LHLLHLL} and [たかいから]{LHLLL}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

から of 高い/こと/から is "from"
から of 高い/から is "because"

If I translate, I use these structures

〜ことから
「支持率が高いこと」 shows 「多くの国民が新内閣に期待していること」

〜だから
Because 「支持率が高い」, (we)  「多くの国民が新内閣に期待していることがわかる」

Answer (score 3):

（１）支持率が高い**ことから**、多くの国民が新内閣に期待していることがわかる。
（２）支持率が高い**から**、多くの国民が新内閣に期待していることがわかる

まず最初に、日本語の自然さについて考えます。
（１）は、日本語として自然です。
（２）は、日本語して少しだけ変です。私なら、（３）または（４）のように言い換えます。
ただし、（３）と（４）とを比較すると、「支持率が高い」だけでは「多くの国民が新内閣に期待している」とまでは言い切れないので、（３）ではなく、（４）のように言うと思います。

> （３）支持率が高いから、多くの国民が新内閣に期待しているのだとわかる。
>   （４）支持率が高いから、多くの国民が新内閣に期待しているのだろうと思う。

次に、（１）、（２）の意味を考えます。私の意味の理解は、user10436さんに非常に近いです。(+1 vote)

（１）は次のような意味です。
私/私たちは次のことがわかる：支持率が高いことから多くの国民が新内閣に期待しているということ。

（２）は次のような意味です。
支持率が高いから、私/私たちは、多くの国民が新内閣に期待しているのだとわかる。

Answer (score 1):

AことからB implies a rational belief, logical connection, or cause and effect relationship, similar to AからB. However, when using ことから, A is considered reliable, fact-like, or well-known. Using から alone is more neutral, and doesn't necessarily imply this.

For further information, here's 3000 words:
https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/japanese-grammar-kotokara/

Answer (score 0):

Is the following "decomposition" helpful?

支持率が高いことから、多くの国民が新内閣に期待していることがわかる  reads

支持率が高いこと + から + 多くの国民が新内閣に期待していること + がわかる

*** added  ***

I hope the following parsing helps.

From the fact that 支持率が高い one concludes that 多くの国民が新内閣に期待している

***  added again   ***

First, the construction connects "支持率が高いこと" and "多くの国民が新内閣に期待していること."
And "から" indicates that "支持率が高いこと" is the reason of the conclusion "わかる".

Does it make sense?

Comment: I understand the sentence, but I'm confused because 支持率が高いから still means "because the support rate is high..." why is ことから necessary in this situation?

Comment: I don't feel like this answers the question. With "difference between X and Y" questions, you're supposed to explain the nuances in meaning and when to use X and when to use Y. Parsing the example sentence differently doesn't really answer the question and isn't very helpful for future cases.

Comment: Yeah it makes sense! I was confused because I assumed から from both conjunctions meant "because" so I thought こと was pretty redundant but I see it now, thank you!